# Save current field data in Sharepoint to another instance of the list

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to connect to a SharePoint list via C# and loop through until I find an item in the list that has particular features, then I want to save some data that is in that item and copy it to another item. I am getting an `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException error.`

```
//connect to the SharePoint site
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(@"https://website");
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listName");
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItem(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());


context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//loop through items
foreach (var listItem in items)
{
            string tmp = null;
            if (listItem["fieldName"] != null) 
// this is where get the error when I reach one that isn't null
            {

               if (listItem["fieldName"].ToString() == "criteria")
                {
                    tmp = listItem["fieldName"].ToString();

                    foreach (var listItem2 in items)
                    {
                        if (listItem2["criteria2"].ToString() == tmp)
                        {
                            listItem2["fieldName"] = tmp;
                            listItem2.Update();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

    }
```

Trying to take the value in `listItem["fieldname"]` and save it, and copy it into `listItem2["fieldname"]`.

Currently, I am getting an error: `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException` error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the field.

```
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext(@"http://SP13");
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List23");
            ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

            context.Load(items, item => item.Include(i => i["Title"], i => i["richtext"]));
            context.ExecuteQuery();
```